# Displaying binary number in asm

Tags: assembly, binary, x86, x86-16

I'm trying to do a 'AND' operation but I end up getting the wrong display results.
My codings seems fine but I just dont know why it couldn't display the result I want in binary.

This is my code for the operations:

```
mov ah, 09h
    lea dx,sAnd
    int 21h

    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, sInputX
    int 21h

    mov ah,0ah          
    lea dx,x
    int 21h

    jmp VerifyX

    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, sInputY
    int 21h

    mov ah,0ah          
    lea dx,y
    int 21h

    jmp Operation1

Operation1:
    mov Al, x
    and Al, y
    mov result, Al
    jmp CONVERSION

CONVERSION:
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, result
    int 21h
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading a character string from stdin. So your values in `x` and `y` are strings and not numbers, unless you are converting them, which you don't show here.

Now assume that the user enters `9` as the first string and `3` as the second.

What you will have then is:

```
x = 39h   ; '9'
y = 33h   ; '3'

39h AND 33h = 31h ; '1'
```

Which is correct in this case, However, this will only work for single digit values, because only the low nibble will change and the hinibble stays the same. If you want to enter longer numbers (i.e. 67 and 23) it will not work anymore. So you should convert the numbers to binary values before you do the and operation, and the result must be converted back to a digit string.

Aditionally you are storing the output in `result` and then use `09h` on `int 21h` for output, but this function requires a string with `$` at the end. so if you didn't put this as the second character, you may see garbage on the screen, depending on what `result` contains.